# Simulating any stabilizer code

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, stim

While simulating any Stabilizer code on STIM do we need an explicit encoding circuit before performing circuit-level noise simulation and error-correction ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Stim needs you to explain your code as a circuit, so you end up needing things like encoders. However, nothing stops you from making the encoding circuit just a series of [`MPP`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#MPP) instructions measuring each stabilizer and observable.

Stim can also automatically generate a bad encoding circuit from the stabilizers. It won't be fault tolerant, but it will produce the correct state:

```python
import stim
stabilizers_and_obs = [
    # stabilizers of perfect code
    stim.PauliString("XZZX_"),
    stim.PauliString("_XZZX"),
    stim.PauliString("X_XZZ"),
    stim.PauliString("ZX_XZ"),
    # observable to prepare
    stim.PauliString("ZZZZZ"),
]
tableau = stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers(stabilizers_and_obs)

print(tableau.to_circuit("elimination").diagram())
# q0: -X-@-X-H-@-@---X-------------------------------------------S-S-------
#      | | |   | |   |
# q1: -|-|-|---|-|---|-X-@-X-H-S-@-@---X---------------------------S-S-----
#      | | |   | |   | | | |     | |   |
# q2: -@-X-@---|-|-H-@-|-|-|---S-X-|---|-X-@-X-H-@-@-----------------S-S---
#              | |     | | |       |   | | | |   | |
# q3: ---------X-|-----@-X-@-------|-H-@-|-|-|-H-X-|-X-@-X-H-S-@-----------
#                |                 |     | | |     | | | |     |
# q4: -----------X-------------H---X-----@-X-@-H---X-@-X-@-----X-H-----S-S-
```

There's a more compact state-prep circuit method coming in v1.13 called `"graph_state"`:

```python
# Needs v1.13.dev or later
print(tableau.to_circuit("graph_state").diagram())
#         /-----------\ /-\
# q0: -RX-@-@-@---------Z---
#         | | |
# q1: -RX-|-|-|-@-@---------
#         | | | | |
# q2: -RX-@-|-|-@-|-@-@-X-H-
#           | |   | | |
# q3: -RX---@-|---|-@-|-----
#             |   |   |
# q4: -RX-----@---@---@-Z---
#         \-----------/ \-/
```

There will also be `"mpp_state"` and `"mpp_state_unsigned"` which just measure the stabilizers using `MPP`, which is what I always do. If it's not fault tolerant anyways, no point in worrying about the details.

Comment: just to confirm if I got it right: You are suggesting to start the data qubits in all |0> state and project this state into simultaneous +1-eigenspace of all the stabilizers using MPP instruction. The final resultant state will be our code space.

Comment: @OmprakashChandra that's right. Assuming you don't need the initialization itself to be fault tolerant, that is sufficient.

Comment: how can we force the state into +1 eigenspace of the stabilizers? Is there a specific instruction in STIM accomplishing this? How do you do it?

Comment: You can use feedback operations and the destabilizers of the code to force them. But what I always do is just include the initial measurement in the detector/observable declarations which makes it work regardless of the initial measurement result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have rewritten the circuit in my own way and it's working now.

Comment: There is one more question: I am using a 4-qubit cat state as ancilla for every X/Z stabilizer measurement, measure them all in X-basis and finally put detector XORing the four measurement outcomes. So should we put detectors in similar way that we do for custom surface code circuit (where we use just one ancilla)?

Comment: @OmprakashChandra If `circuit.detector_error_model()` doesn't raise an exception, and `circuit.count_determined_measurements() == circuit.num_detectors + circuit.num_observables`, that's a good sign you've got the detectors correct.

Comment: the last command is really helpful. I am still working on putting the detectors right. Will let you know how it goes. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: is there any problem if we put more detectors than needed? i.e. redundant detectors?

Comment: @OmprakashChandra It depends. In general I'd say to avoid redundancy. On the other hand, in the toric code there are two redundant detectors that complete the surface of the donut so that you get local decoding.

Comment: I see. What if ``circuit.detector_error_model()" doesn't raise an exception but ``circuit.count_determined_measurements() == circuit.num_detectors + circuit.num_observables" is false? In my case I have put less detectors than total number of determined measurements. Will that affect the outcome?

Comment: @OmprakashChandra That usually means you forgot to annotate some of the detectors.  If `len(circuit.shortest_graphlike_error()) == 1` or some other small number independent of code distance then you *definitely* forgot some detectors.

Comment: I am getting ``len(circuit.shortest_graphlike_error()) == 1" True for my circuit. :(. I need to revise the setup of the detectors. Is there any simpler way to find which detectors we are missing?

Comment: @OmprakashChandra Look at the location of the error returned by the shortest graphlike error method. There needs to be a detector near there.

Comment: do you mean the command: circuit.shortest_graphlike_error() ? It doesn't returns any error but  a collection of stim.DemTargetWithCoords(dem_target=stim.target_relative_detector_id(1), coords=[0, 3, 0].

Comment: @OmprakashChandra Ah, use `circuit.explain_detector_error_model_errors` to turn that into circuit locations.

Comment: StackExchange won't let me put more comments after a while. Could we move to somewhere else if that's fine with you? Email?

Answer (score 0):

To supplement @Craig Gidney's answer, the [TQEC project](https://github.com/QCHackers/tqec) is under development for the purpose of assisting researchers who build error-correcting circuits. This project takes Stim as a dependency in circuit construction on the backend.

Comment: thanks for this. I will have a look at the project.